# Understanding the Export Mechanism of Perfect Lineup App to Dream11

Tags: python, android, export, artificial-intelligence

I am curious about the process by which the Perfect Lineup app is able to generate teams using AI and then export them seamlessly to Dream11 within seconds. I would like to gain insights into the technical aspects of this exporting mechanism.

I am trying that's same thing can fit on a python program and I want to know the solution for it.how to export teams

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.